# Blender 3.1. use_gpu_subdivision, How can I turn that Option on with python code?

Tags: python, customization

How can I turn that new 3.1 Blender Feature *Use GPU Subdivision* with Python code?

I tried with `bpy.types.PreferencesSystem.use_gpu_subdivision = True` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple :D

`bpy.context.preferences.system.use_gpu_subdivision = True`

> Enable GPU acceleration for evaluating the last subdivision surface modifiers in the stack

[Link to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PreferencesSystem.html#bpy.types.PreferencesSystem.use_gpu_subdivision)

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I added a little bit of info to your answer. Thanks for your contribution !